# Sidekiq Delayed Class won't fail when Error is raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I have a delayed class which performs a request at an external webservice that I would like to retry if the request failed.

```
class MyModel

  def self.does_request(record_name)
    response = self.post(record_name)
    if response.status == 404
      raise StandardError
    end
  end

  def self.post(record_name)
    # HTTP request which returns the response
  end

end
```

I'm calling the method as `MyModel.delay.does_request('new_value')`

Unfortunately, Sidekiq is not handling the Error I raise, it simply marks the job as processed on the WebUI. I have tried raising the error on a separate Worker's `perform` method and works fine, but I'm avoiding creating a worker specifically for that as I have several requests on that class and creating a Worker for each sounds a bit too much.

How can I retry the method without using a Worker for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after restarting my sidekiq proccess it worked, apparently just  doing `reload!` on my rails console isn't enough.